# How to invert boolean byte coding function?

Tags: functions, inverse

I've got simple byte coding function:

> y = x and E0 or x and 1F xor 05

Now I want to express x = ...? Is it possible using Mathematica (for more complex ones), please? TIA

Correct answer (right?):

> x = y and 05 or y and FA

Answer (score 2):

Could do this by expanding into explicit bit lists and solving mod 2.

Set up variables:

```
byteLen = 8;
xbits = Array[x, byteLen];
ybits = Array[y, byteLen];
```

Provide constants:

```
c1 = 16^^E0;
c2 = 16^^1F;
c3 = 16^^05;
```

Code to convert numbers to bit lists and code to rewrite bitwise logical operations as arithmetic ops.

```
numberToBits[num_] := IntegerDigits[num, 2, byteLen]

and[a_, b_] := a*b
or[a_, b_] := a + b + a*b
xor[a_, b_] := a + b
```

Here is the example in question. The precedence of `xor` was not obvious to me so I took a guess. I use `Solve` to do the work.

```
Solve[
 ybits == or[and[xbits, numberToBits[c1]], 
   xor[and[xbits, numberToBits[c2]], numberToBits[c3]]], xbits, 
 Modulus -> 2]

(* Out[121]= {{x[1] -> 
   ConditionalExpression[C[8], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]], 
  x[2] -> ConditionalExpression[C[7], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]], 
  x[3] -> ConditionalExpression[C[6], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]], 
  x[4] -> ConditionalExpression[C[5], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]], 
  x[5] -> ConditionalExpression[C[4], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]], 
  x[6] -> ConditionalExpression[C[3], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]], 
  x[7] -> ConditionalExpression[C[2], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]], 
  x[8] -> ConditionalExpression[C[1], 
    y[1] == C[8] && y[2] == C[7] && y[3] == C[6] && y[4] == C[5] && 
     y[5] == C[4] && y[6] == 1 + C[3] && y[7] == C[2] && 
     y[8] == 1 + C[1]]}} *)
```

Offhand I'm not sure how to get the solution nicely parametrized in terms of the `y` variables. One can do this by omitting the `Modulus->2` setting to `Solve`, but I doubt this is a generally safe approach.